# SystemC sc_signal array memory bounds

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, systemc

I've been trying to make an array of signals with the SystemC specifications, but have been running into some segmentation faults in a specific unexpected situation. This is leading me to believe that there is some sort of a memory bound for the number of variables one can have using SystemC, which I am interested in confirming, as well as finding a work-around.

Consider these examples of a sc_main function:

```
sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    sc_signal<float>    values[100];
    return 0;
}
```

This one runs perfectly fine. However when I run the code below...

```
sc_main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    sc_signal<float>    values[100][800];
    return 0;
}
```

I get a segmentation fault: 11. (80,000 signals)

I've found further that I don't get a fault at 40,000 signals, so there must be some sort of a bound between 40,000 and 50,000. Can anyone confirm that this is indeed what should be happening, or have any ideas of how I can get around this limitation, and have a larger amount of signals?

Comment: What is `sc_signal`? How big it is? Can your stack (where local variables usually are stored) handle 80000 such objects? Remember that the stack is a limited resource, and that processes in Windows usually have only 1MiB stack.

Comment: I see, yes sc_signal<float> takes up 128 bytes. Thanks for the insight. I've adjusted the amount of memory allocated to the stack and now have it working.

Comment: `values[100][800];` that's a fairly big array to put on the stack.

Comment: As a rule, you should have no more than 4096 bytes per stack frame. Otherwise, you might *miss* the guard page, and start overwriting random stuff *instead* of crashing. With GCC, `-Werror=stack-usage=4096`

Answer (score 0):

On 64bit Linux `sizeof(sc_signal<float>)` is 192 bytes. Default stack size is 8 Mbytes.  So you can allocate approximately 41000 signals on stack, that correlates with your experimental results.

In general you should not allocate SystemC objects on stack. Real world designs in general do not fit into 8 MBytes. Instead allocate on heap:

```
#include <systemc.h>

struct test_module : sc_module {
    sc_signal<float>    values[100][800];
    SC_CTOR(test_module) {}
};

int sc_main (int argc, char**argv) {
    auto tmod0 = std::make_unique<test_module>("tmod0");
    sc_start();
    return 0;
}
```